# Running Total With Negative to Positive X Axis Reflects Incorrect Running Total When No Data

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a period of four years I am comparing. Each day the amount of positive and negative gains of sales is reflected in the data.

**The raw data looks as such:**

[image: [Raw Data]

**My dax calculation is:**

```
Actions running total in From Start = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Total Data'[Actions]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('Total Data'[From Start]),
        ISONORAFTER('Total Data'[From Start], MAX('Total Data'[From Start]), DESC)
    )
)
```

**This is what my chart looks like:**

[image: [Problem Chart]

**But the chart should look more aligned as such:**

[image: [Similar Chart]

The problem chart lies on a negative to a positive axis. Centered around a central important date. Each negative date is that many days before the date. Each positive date is reflected after the date of importance. This axis comes from the "From  Start" Column in my raw data.

However, if the axis is positive, such as in the similar chart, the running total is just from the start of data.

Every time an entry of data does not display data (Example: The raw data for 4/2/2017 didn't have any values so it just doesn't exist) the chart displays a large total value. I need to find a way to reflect this data with a negative to a positive axis while evening the line out to look similar to the similar chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing what's happening is that the second argument in your `ISONORAFTER` function is returning a blank value for terms that don't have data for that date and therefore treating it as if it were a zero (notice that the value is the same height as at zero).

To remedy this, let's remove any extra filter context other than the `From Start` value from the axis. This way it pulls in the date offset even if that particular `Term` doesn't have a value for it.

```
Actions running total in From Start =
VAR FromStart =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Total Data'[From Start] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Total Data', 'Total Data'[From Start] )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Total Data'[Actions] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLSELECTED ( 'Total Data'[From Start] ),
            ISONORAFTER ( 'Total Data'[From Start], FromStart, DESC )
        )
    )
```

Comment: This worked extremely well. And provided a solution to a problem we have had for awhile in our reporting. Great stuff and thank you!